# Why delete cannot be used without new?

Tags: c++

I know that delete should always be used with new operator. And I am getting Segmentation fault with following code. But what is the reason for this.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class A
    {
        public:
            void fun()
            {
                delete this;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {

        A a;
        a.fun();


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How can you delete that which has no memory allocated by new?

Comment: `I know that delete should always be used with new operator.` Actually you do not seem to know this.

Comment: You're trying to `delete` memory allocated on the stack and will result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Because the language standard says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete must be used with new.Why?

When new operator is applied on some object, `compiler do some internal book-keeping` ( for which you don't need to go in detail), so that delete would be able to properly de-allocate that memory. 
You would have heard that destructors are called only on objects `which are fully constructed`. One reason for not allowing destructors to be called on `not-fully-constructed objects is efficiency`. If destructors were allowed then extra book-keeping should be maintained so that delete get to know how much bits of object are constructed so as to delete only that much memory.

Now what goes at higher level?

When you use new two things happen:-

```
1) adequate amount of memory is allocated.
2) Then constructors are called to initialize object in that memory.
```

When you use delete two other things happen:-

```
1) destructors are called for the objects in memory.
2) memory is de-allocated then.
```

If you only use delete how could compiler then perform proper operation.

Using delete on stack objects:-

If the object was allocated on the stack, your compiler would generate a call to its destructor at the end of its scope. This means you will call the destructor twice.

Besides calling the destructor twice, you will also attempt to deallocate a memory that was never allocated.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I welcome your comment. But just telling that answer is misleading won't help anyone.If you could provide some explanation it would be much helpful for stack overflow community. Apart from that I would also learn something.

Comment: Earlier (in a removed comment) you cited part of a paragraph written by Herb Sutter. You omitted the first two sentences: "There is a reason why C++ refuses to call destructors for objects that haven't been fully constructed, and it's not simply to make your life more difficult. It's because it would, in many cases, be a nonsensical thing -- possibly a harmful thing -- to do." It would be nonsensical, harmful, because the not constructed sub-objects can have indeterminate values, and do not in general have valid class invariants. Cleaning up such is not meaningful and not possible.

Comment: Remaining part of that paragraph is :- "If a destructor were invoked on an object that wasn't fully constructed, how would the
destructor know what to do? The only way it could know would be if bits had been added to each object
indicating how much of the constructor had been executed. Then the destructor could check the bits and (maybe)
figure out what actions to take. Such bookkeeping would slow down constructors, and it would make each object
larger, too. C++ avoids this overhead, but the price you pay is that partially constructed objects aren't
automatically destroyed"

Comment: The part you chose to cite was where Herb went on to discuss a possible but inefficient way to implement things so that destructors would not actually do anything for not constructed sub-objects. I.e. to avoid executing user code in such destructors. He pointed out that this approach, with the destructor itself deciding, would require extra per-object data and would be inefficient. Instead, the usual implementation is that such destructors are just not called at all (from the failing constructor): it calls destructors only on the so far successfully constructed sub-objects.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I really appreciate that you went on and provided the details. Yes I agree with you that it would be harmful as you don't know what user could do with that not-fully-constructed-object. But other reason would be inefficiency. That's why I mentioned "One reason" in my answer. I could say that implementing such approach would be both harmful as well as inefficient.Might be I am not entirely correct with my assumption but this discussion would surely help anyone. ~Thanks

Comment: **Errata**: I see now (scanning further down the google result list) that it was written by Scott Meyers, not Herb Sutter. I just used the author name the OP mentioned in the earlier, now deleted comment.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `delete` must only be used with pointers obtained from `new` (or nullpointers) is the same as the reason why you must use `delete[]` for pointers obtained with `new T[]`, namely the guiding principle that in C++

**you don't pay for what you don't use.**

Generally.

`delete` *could* have supported arbitrary pointers as arguments, just checking whether any given pointer argument was earlier produced by `new`, and only in that case doing anything. But it would be inefficient, in general. It would be a service that most C++ programmers would not need and would not use, but would still be paying for.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to delete something on the stack.

Besides you should never use `delete this` (except in *VERY* rare circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

int main()
    {

```
    A a=new A();
    a.fun();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please explain your answer, this answer has no educational value